# Using jQuery for Dom Outlining.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am a newbie in jQuery and javascript, so this might seem as a trivial question. I want to use the DOM Outliner code found [here](https://github.com/andrewchilds/jQuery.DomOutline) in an html page that I have created.

My html page source is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <h3>Dom Outlining</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="jquery.dom-outline-1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var myExampleClickHandler = function (element) { console.log('Clicked element:', element); }
        var myDomOutline = DomOutline({ onClick: myExampleClickHandler });

        // Start outline:
        myDomOutline.start();

        // Stop outline (also stopped on escape/backspace/delete keys):
        myDomOutline.stop();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div class="first class">
        <p> This is a division.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't seem to select and highlight the element as required. Can someone tell me what's missing in my code?

Comment: Have you check "jquery.dom-outline-1.0.js" javascript is load properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are stoping highlighting as soon as it starts

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var myExampleClickHandler = function (element) { console.log('Clicked element:', element); }
    var myDomOutline = DomOutline({ onClick: myExampleClickHandler });

    // Start outline:
    myDomOutline.start();

    // Stop outline (also stopped on escape/backspace/delete keys):
    //myDomOutline.stop();
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b8lWZ9ght6WTt8y50odP?p=preview)

In ideal implementation there will be a start and stop buttons as I added in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `myDomOutline.stop();` :)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var myExampleClickHandler = function (element) { console.log('Clicked element:', element); }
        var myDomOutline = DomOutline({ onClick: myExampleClickHandler });

        // Start outline:
        myDomOutline.start();

        // Stop outline (also stopped on escape/backspace/delete keys):
       // myDomOutline.stop();
    });
```

You were starting it and then stopping it almost immediately - resulting in nothing!

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/vJYya/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <h3>Dom Outlining</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="jquery.dom-outline-1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var myDomOutline = DomOutline({ 
                onClick: function (element) { 
                    console.log('Clicked element:', element); 
                }
            });

            $('#start').click(function(){
                myDomOutline.start();
            });

            $('#stop').click(function(){
                myDomOutline.stop();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="start" type="button" value="Start outline"/>
    <input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop outline"/>

    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div class="first class">
        <p> This is a division.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```